# Change parent div height according to child img height, without exceeding parent divs max-width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have yet to find any good CSS code that solves my problem, and that works in all major browsers.
That being said, safari automatically does this whenever I use `max-height: 90%` in the parent div, and sets `max-height: 100%` in the child img. However, Mozilla does not.

Is there any cross browser solution for making sure the img does not expand more than the height of the parent div. But the parent div can adjust to the childs height, and be limited to its own `max-height`?

I also accept jQuery, but prefer CSS in the answer.

When it comes to width this will always be `width: 60%` in the parent div, and `max-width: 100%` in the child img.

**Code**

```
.fullScaleContent{
    position: fixed;
    width: 60%;
    max-height: 90%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 2% auto;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -55%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -55%); 
    -ms-transform: translate (-50%, -55%);
}
.fullScaleContent img{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

**Image examples: First image is height limit in safari, second is in Firefox. I need both to be similar to safari. PS: Black border is the actual border of the div**

[image: limited height - safari]

[image: limited height - firefox]

**Limited width - works fine in both - height is adjusted according to img, with max width 60%**

[image: limited width - both]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used [`object-fit: contain`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)

If you use `position`, use it on your image to so it's in the flow.

Review Snippet in full page and resize it.

#### SNIPPET

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.fullScaleContent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 60%;
  max-height: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 2% auto;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -55%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -55%);
  -ms-transform: translate (-50%, -55%);
}
.fullScaleContent img {
  position: relative;
  object-fit: contain;
  min-width: 128px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<figure class="fullScaleContent">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png">
</figure>
```

Comment: This wouldn't be SEO friendly though... Is there any way to do it using the <img> tag?

Comment: Worked perfectly! :) Does all modern browsers support this? Also, can I replace figure with div?

Comment: No, Edge and IE do not support `object-fit`, refer to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit), but there's a [polyfill](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images/). Yes, sir, figure may be replaced by any block element without any consequences that I'm aware of (unless you are concerned about semantics), div is fine.